# MongoDB aggregate: Unwind then summing leads to concatenated strings

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I have a mongo collection that has documents in the format:

```
{
   "_id" : 56345
   "location" : "Watertown"
   "grocery_stores" : [
      {
         "street": "Main"
         "size": 3243
         "name": "Main Street Deli"
      },
      {
         "street": "Western"
         "size": 13432
         "name": "Surplus Groceries"
      }
   ] 
}
```

My goal is to find the total count of each grocery store name across all locations. To do this, I used an aggregate pipeline with unwind and group. However, the results returned seem to be recombining components from the grocery store arrays rather than treating them each individually.

#### Query:

```
db.grocery.aggregate([
   {$project: {_id:1, location:1, stores:"$grocery_stores.name"}},
   {$unwind: "$stores"},
   {$group: {_id: "$stores"}},
   {$group: {_id:"$_id", count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

#### Expected Results

```
{ "_id" : "Main Street Deli", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Surplus Groceries", "count" : 1 }
...
```

#### Achieved Results

```
{ "_id" : "Main Street Deli,Surplus Groceries", "count" : 1 }
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your aggregation query returns the output as shown in the _Expected Results_. So, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
db.grocery.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$grocery_stores"},{ $group : { _id : "$grocery_stores.name" , count: {$sum: 1}} }])
```

Result

```
{ "_id" : "Surplus Groceries", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Main Street Deli", "count" : 3 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. When I run your query, I still run into the same issue, but if I use your query to group by grocery_stores.street it works as expected. I'm guessing there is some weird underlying structure to the database I can't see. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what issue you having running my query. Remove group stage and run and see output first. Then you can add group back. When you are grouping, think of it as you have bucket for each grocery store name and in the bucket you are incrementing the counter by 1 each time you find same name.